# How to select lots of counts of lots of different criterias

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, count

I'm trying to do a detailed Member Search page. It uses Ajax in every aspect like Linkedin did on search pages.

But I don't know how I can select counts of multiple criterias. You can see what I meant by the attachment. I mean, if I select every count with different queries it's gonna take forever.

Should I store the count values on another table? Then, further development will be hard and time consuming.

I need your advices.

In this web site, you enter just a keyword and it shows you the all available fields order by count DESC;

[image]

Comment: Can you say what the performance is at the moment?

Comment: If I select all counts with different queries, page loads in almost 10 seconds and more sometimes. You know, in order to list results like that and if I use multiple queries, then I have to use the same WHERE statement in every query. That's performance killer. I just wonder how they do this? And also if I use JOIN statements then results with no records wouldn't return so I would have to OUTER JOIN which is a killer again.

Comment: Can you show us your current query?  Also, could it be an indexing issue?  Do you have the right indexes?  Have your indexes become too fragmented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) that groups by your criteria and uses COUNT_BIG to get totals.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TagCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT Tag, COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountOfDocs
    FROM dbo.Docs
    GROUP BY Tag
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TagCount ON dbo.TagCount (Tag)
```